# inserting value in to SQL table and use SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert values from one table in to the other, with an additonal parameter that is required.  For instance:

```
INSERT INTO table1(someInt, someOtherInt, name, someBit)    
SELECT someInt, someOtherInt, name FROM table2
```

someBit is not allowed to be null, and I need to set it to False, but I am not quite sure how use it in the same INSERT statement.  (Im using SQL 2005 if it matters)

edit: Ouch...looks like i threw out filet mignon to lions :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe

```
INSERT INTO table1(someInt, someOtherInt, name, someBit)    
SELECT someInt, someOtherInt, name, 0
FROM table2
```

Comment: yeah, sometimes we stuck ourselves, it can happen to anyone of us

Comment: I type too slow to get answers in on these. I started when there was no answer and there were already 3 by the time I hit "Submit" :)

Comment: I'm late for this karma feast, so I'll just upvote everyone :)

Comment: Thanks guys.  the quick responses were much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps

`INSERT INTO table1(someInt, someOtherInt, name, someBit)

SELECT someInt, someOtherInt, name, 0 FROM table2`

?

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO table1(someInt, someOtherInt, name, someBit)    
SELECT someInt, someOtherInt, name, 0 FROM table2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just hard-code the value in the SELECT like so:

```
INSERT INTO
     dbo.table1
(
     someInt,
     someOtherInt,
     name,
     someBit
)
SELECT
     someInt,
     someOtherInt,
     name,
     0
FROM
     dbo.table2
```

Comment: Why not just set the default on the table?

Comment: 0 may not always be the default

Answer (score 2):

You could also define a default value for that column on the destination table.  This way you wouldn't have to reference it all in your insert statement.

Lets say your SomeBit is the Active flag or status on a customer table. 
Active 0 = off/false/no 
Active 1 = on/true/yes.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Customer_Active]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Active]
```